# Do you get penalized after a certain number of duplicate questions?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, post-ban

Is it possible to be penalized (e.g., be banned from asking future questions or have points deducted) after having a certain number of your questions closed as duplicates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not directly, but if you keep getting questions closed, you might get hit with a question ban.

Its relatively trivial to avoid getting complete duplicates - the site often prompts you, and where your question is substantially different, it helps to quote the other question when asking.

If you keep *asking* duplicate questions, you might want to re-look how you search the site, and try to adjust yourself, rather than wondering whether you'd get penalised

Comment: `s/how you search/if you search`

Comment: If you're not searching, you're not searching enough. I very often start asking a question, get popped a duplicate as I type, and check it out, either to find an answer, or to throw it a bounty